# Creating 1 byte data using struct.pack in python

Tags: python, struct, hex, byte, pack

I am new to python programming and I am writing a script that uses struct.pack() to convert a float number into a hex string. I have to pack this float number as 1 byte. I understand the size of float is 4 bytes. But is there are a work around to save a value of 0.1 as 1 byte using struct.pack().

I tried the following but that gives me error.

```
struct.pack('!B', 0.1)
```

If not, is there any alternate approach to save it as 1 byte INTEGER?
I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: I don't think that struct is what you need, you want your own format, with 1 byte you lose a lot of percision, you need to implement a dump and load functions for your format to hold in 1 byte...

Comment: @AnnZen, Here's the error:
struct.error: argument for 's' must be a bytes object